# RoR ActiveResource self.to_json : Difference between 3.2.1 and 3.0.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, activeresource

ARes 3.0.7

```
user = User.find(123)
# response.body outputs {"id":"123","lastName":"Jones","firstName":"Bob"}
user.to_json = {"firstName":"Bob","id":"123","lastName":"Jones"}
```

ARes 3.2.1

```
user = User.find(123)
# response.body outputs {"id":"123","lastName":"Jones","firstName":"Bob"}
user.to_json = {"user":{"firstName":"Bob","id":"123","lastName":"Jones"}}
```

How do I make ARes 3.2.1 behave like ARes 3.0.7? Is there a configuration that touches upon .to_json directly?

Background:
I am upgrading from RoR 3.0.7 to RoR 3.2.1. Old environment was JRuby 1.6.2, Ruby 1.8.7. New environment is JRuby 1.6.7, Ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: I would, but I'm not using ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was changed in rails 3.1 I believe.

Put the following in your `config/application.rb` or inside an initializer to set it back.

```
ActiveResource::Base.include_root_in_json = true
```

Please note, you must restart the server for this to take effect.

**update**

Looks like this currently does not modify the output JSON.  There is a pull request on Github however.  https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/4874

Comment: I'm using ActiveResource, but still using the equivalent in ActiveResource does nothing.
ActiveResource::Base.include_root_in_json = true
true or false do nothing.

Comment: Thanks, but there's no difference whether I set it to true or false.

Comment: @MarkPeterson You are quite correct.  Please see this pull request:  https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/4874